# Does 1 dotnetnuke installation support multiple active directory logins

Tags: active-directory, dotnetnuke

I have a client who's proposed a project that will be offered to enterprise customers as a subscription service. Each customer will be assigned a child portal where their employees will login to the portal to use the app. The child portals would be setup as subdomains such as **company1.example.com**, **company2.example.com**,..and so forth.

Since most enterprises use active directory for membership, he would like to offer this as an option for login. Now the question is, **does a single installation of DNN allow each child portal to have its own separate active directory membership?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could most likely configure this option, as the AD settings are per portal, but you might simply reach out to DNNCorp to ask questions about AD as they have AD supported in the professional edition of the platform.

Comment: Thanks **Chris**, I will check out with them.